# Поиск по адресу, выдаёт ошибку 403

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

1) Есть запрос
[https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=ваш](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88) API-ключ&geocode=Тверская+6

2) Есть активный Api_key

3)При запросе [https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=МОЙ_API&geocode=Тверская+6](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%99_API&geocode=%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+6)

Выдаёт в браузере

```
<error>
<statusCode>403</statusCode>
<error>Forbidden</error>
<message>Invalid key</message>
</error>
```

Я хочу получить просто ответ геокодера.Яндекс

Comment: `Примечание. Ключ будет активирован в течение 15 минут после получения.` - 15 минут прошло? ключ скопирован без ошибок?

Comment: Больше часа прошло, а толку нет - 403
В личном кабинете статус "Активен"

Answer (score 0):

Обычно ключ активируется в течение 15 минут, но иногда на это уходит больше времени. Если прошло больше часа, а ключ так и не заработал, нужно писать в техподдержку